# Excel order of process question (REGARDING IF and AND)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

So when you use `IF()` and `AND()` at the same time, does excel run all the logics even if it fails on the first logic?

Example:

```
IF(AND(A1=1, A2=2, A3=3), "YES!", "NO!")
```

So lets say that A1 is NOT equals to 1. will excel go ahead and see if A2 is equals to 2 and A3 is equals to 3? or will it just stop at A1=1 and then skip the entire `AND()` function?

Just was a curiosity.

Comment: Testing this with `=AND(A1="",MAP(A1:A999999,LAMBDA(s,s="")))` made it quite clear to me that it will go over each parameter within `AND()` since time to calculate the 2nd parameter is quite high and the overall time did not improve when changing `A1` to say 'x'. You can also double-check this when you step through a formula using the Evaluate function. You will notice each parameter within `AND()` is getting calculated before the overall `TRUE` or `FALSE` is given.

Comment: I assumed that too since I am getting an error with my formula.  My issue is that the 2nd and 3rd logic is only calculable if the first logic is TRUE, but since it is FALSE it is giving me a #VALUE error (unless I am missing something very obvious). Is there a way to make excel stop at first FALSE logic?

Comment: Sure, you can nest multiple `IF()` statement: `=IF(A1=1,IF(A2=2,IF(A3=3,"Yes","No"),;"No"),"No")`, this would atleast stop testing `A2` and `A3` if `A1` is allready `FALSE`. About the error: That could be due to a few reasons. For example, your input in either of these cells is an error, or your formula is simply faulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you even know you can test this yourself? Just use the "Evaluate Formula" tool ("Formulas" menu, "Formula auditing"), as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

Click "Evaluate":

[image]

As you see, the value of "A1" gets filled in. Click "Evaluate" again:

[image]

The first equality is seen to be "FALSE", but the value "A2" gets underlined, not a good sign, and indeed:

[image]

Altough the first "FALSE" should be enough to get a "FALSE" result, still all other cases are calculated.

Although this seems to be stupid, what about this formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1=1; A2=2; A3/0=3); "YES!"; "NO!")
```

In the third "condition", I divide by zero, generating a "#DIV/0" result.
Following your proposal, that mistake would not even be detected.

Comment: Did not even know there was an Evaluate Formula function in excel, thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I just did some tests and it seems like excel does test all logics, and even if the first logic is FALSE it will continue testing all the remaining logics and if **any** of the logics is not calculable, you get an error.

As mentioned by a comment from someone, using several IFs would be a solution, albeit a rather annoying one. In my case it was easier to make all the logics calculable so excel can simply determine the result and move on.

Answer (score 0):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are actually not the only possible outputs of `AND()` function.
It can also return an error.

To determine whether all parameters are valid, Excel still need to evaluate them.